# Neo4j in the cloud

Tags: spring, cloud, neo4j, cloud-foundry

Is anyone aware of cloud services (PaaS) which could be suitable for a spring/neo4j application. Anything to look out for?

Comment: I've asked cloudbees about this, still waiting on an answer. Will post response here.

Comment: Short answer from cloudbees....no. They currently only support mongodb and couch.

Comment: Had a chat with Heroku. They are offering Neo4j in private beta at the moment. I don't think it'll be too long before they go public...well I hope not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, [Amazon EBS](http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Neo4j_in_the_Cloud) is currently the only stable option, [Heroku](http://addons.heroku.com/neo4j) is in private beta and [Cloud Foundry](http://blogs.vmware.com/console/2011/08/micro-cloud-foundry-open-paas-on-your-laptop-available-today.html) is work in progress.

Comment: CloudFoundry now supports Neo4J. A Neo4J/Spring app is listed as a [favorite](http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2011/05/27/a-few-of-our-favorite-cloud-foundry-apps/) and is open sourced on [github](https://github.com/oxlade39/graphflow).

Answer (score 3):

Neo4j is available on Heroku now. Details in this document at infoq. http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/good-relationships-spring-data

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Jelastic PaaS has recently updated a blog post for Neo4j support.
I have found it here: http://blog.jelastic.com/2013/03/21/neo4j-in-the-cloud/