# Ways to cloud host embedded neo4j server with jruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, jruby, neo4j, cloud-hosting

I have a rails server using the embedded neo4j server and the neo4j.rb gem. Using rails 3.1, jruby 1.7 and neo4j.rb 2.0 what is the best way to host a production server?

I looked into Heroku but the neo4j addon only supports the restful interface. I'd have been okay with that except I've already coded for the embedded server using the neo4j.rb gem and don't want to have to rewrite to use something like the neography gem.

I've considered amazon's ec2 service, since there's an AMI for neo4j, but I've not any experience with that and would want to be positive this would work. I think this might also require the amazon EBS service too.

I'm also completely open to other alternatives, but I've a preference for solutions which don't involves too much configuration before getting things running (like heroku would have been if it could have handled the embedded version).

There's also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649319/neo4j-in-the-cloud) but I've posted mine since it's specific to jruby rails and because that question was answered over a year ago (by one day, actually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ec2 works good, you could of course even take a dedicated hosting provider like www.hetzner.de, depending on where you need the servers being placed.

Comment: If I went with ec2 would it be possible to have multiple servers accessing the one database? Or is the embedded neo4j version forced into a 1-1 mapping to the rails servers, requiring neo4j-HA to scale horizontally?

Comment: Yes, using Embedded Neo4j form different machines is most easily done with an HA setup, where the instances sync between each other, even over EC2 instances.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the same scenario with Jelastic and found that is as well working well and no hassle to configure the same.

- > http://jelastic.com/docs/jelastic-jruby-deploy

> http://blog.jelastic.com/2013/03/21/neo4j-in-the-cloud/
>   
>   though I didn't try with AWS . so I cant say anything about that.